# How to unzip a zip file in django , which contains .shp , .prj , .shx and .dbf , thus being able to upload in the database?

Tags: python, django

I have uploaded a zip file using django in a local directory . How do I unzip it , and store it in 3 different files ?

Ok . Let me explain my problem a bit more in detail .

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.handle(request.FILES['file_obj'])
            #form.save() # if a modelform
            #form.cleaned_data['user'] = request.user
            z = zipfile.ZipFile('file_obj')
        for files in z.namelist():
            file(files,'wb').write(z.read(files))

        z.close()

            return render_to_response('uploaded.html', RequestContext(request,{}))
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', RequestContext(request,{'form': form})
```

)

This is my upload form , which is supposed to work . file_obj contains the uploaded zip file . But it doesnt give any output .

Comment: Did you look in the Python documentation for anything to do with zip files?

Comment: I did . extract and extractall are not working properly .

Comment: Those look like GIS files, have you tried GIS specific packages?

Comment: I have edited my question to explain my problem .

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look like you're actually opening the upload, but a file in the current directory called 'file_obj'. You want something more like

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(request.FILES['file_obj'])
```

also I might be wrong, but i don't think you need the form.handle() call at all, at least I've never used it, but i might stand corrected.

Also, you want to be very careful here, as you're writing out to the filenames contained in the zipfile, which for all you know could be absolute paths somewhere. You need to be very careful with that. In case I didn't say it, be careful with user created content, it might be malicious.

Comment: Tried that already but doesn't work . The zip file still remains without being extracted .